# Value ... is not of the correct type

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

When trying to insert data via `IDbCommand` (`StoredProdecure`) I'm getting an error:

> Value 'my_value' is not of the correct type.

```
Details:
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.GetAndFixParameter(String spName, MySqlSchemaRow param, Boolean realAsFloat, MySqlParameter returnParameter)
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.CheckParameters(String spName)
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.Resolve(Boolean preparing)
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   ...
```

What I do is:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("pmy_value", p.my_value.ID));
```

Where ID is defined as

```
public byte? ID //VM property definition...
```

Which is not null when executing (value is 2) - and is checked for null beforehand.

In the database table the column is defined as:

```
`ID` tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

and (FK in other table)

```
`my_value` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
```

and inside of the procedure:

```
pmy_value tinyint,
```

I have tried changing the datatype in the procedure (smallint, int, text, ...), but this does not change the error at all.

This has worked before without change to the referenced tables, which is strange enough.
Also I have extracted the values from all added `MySqlParameter`s and did execute the procedure manually which yielded expected results without an error.

What could be the issue here ?

Comment: What version of MySql.Data? It sounds a little bit like this bug report, https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101302, although that one has been fixed. You could try switching to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ which tends to be less buggy. (Disclaimer: package lead developer)

Comment: @BradleyGrainger Indeed it's an older version I am using (8.0.19). I will check out your library and see how easy it can be replaced. Thank you :) - For now I have replaced it with `int` so I was able to continue.